# display total count of items within a date range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a timetable created with `generateseries` and a fact table with a `since_day` and a `to_day` columns, both joined with the `day` column of my generated timetable.

I want to display a visual with a line that should show the growing trend of the total amount of items in the fact table that are between the range of dates.

I've tried with something like:

```
TREND = COUNTROWS( filter( items, items[since_day] >= firstdate( timetable[day] ) && items[to_day] <= lastdate( timetable[day] ) ) )
```

However, this counts the rows within a single period of time, not the cumulative counting that is growing year after year. How can I instrument the CALCULATE to perform a per-period sum of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALLSELECTED` to the get the full range of a sliced/filtered table, then pick the first date.

```
TREND = 
  var firstDay = CALCULATE( firstdate(timetable[day]), ALLSELECTED(timetable[day]) )
  return COUNTROWS( filter( ALL(items), items[since_day] >= firstDay && items[to_day] <= lastdate( timetable[day] ) ) )
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it does not show any difference with  my original expression, and most notably it is not accumulating the number of rows.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't fully understand what you meant by "since_day and a to_day columns, both joined with the day column of my generated timetable." Could you update your question with a snip of the data model showing the relationship between the two? In the meantime, I have update the answer above to have `ALL(items)` in the filter in `COUNTROWS` - see it that fixes it.